# Методы. Вернуть длину строкового представления целого числа

Tags: c#, методы

Я новичок в С#, подскажите, что значит вернуть длину строкового представления целого числа, не понимаю как реализовать данный метод.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Returns the length of the integer's string presentation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="number">Source integer.</param>
        /// <returns>The length of the integer's string presentation.</returns>
    

    public static byte GetLengthWithCascadedIfElse(int number)
        {
            //Add the method implementation. Restriction: the method can only use the cascaded 
                if else statement and comparison operations.
     
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Comment: `number.ToString().Length`, только возврат - `int`

Comment: @KuzCode если на входе int, то выход влезет и в byte

Comment: видимо если число 234, то надо вернуть 3,  если число 98765, то вернуть 5

Comment: @Эникейщик всё верно, я про то, что свойство `Length` возвращает `int`и его нужно закастить до байта

Comment: @KuzCode а как через ifы это всё оформить?

Comment: безпонятия зачем тут вообще `if`-ы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посчитайте логарифм вашего числа и округлите его в меньшую сторону.
Лучше решения для больших чисел с упором на производительность я не знаю.

```
int x = 134534534;
int size = Math.Round(Math.Log10(x));
int size_f = Math.Round(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(x))) + (x < 0 ? 1 : 0);
//size_f - Если число ещё может быть отрицательным
```

Есть ещё 2 варианта:

1. Деление в цикле на 10 - быстро, но не очень оптимально, когда число большое.
2. Привести к строке и посчитать число символов - крайне медленно, но если делать 1 раз, а не для огромного массива чисел - то сойдёт.

Comment: `Деление в цикле на 10 - быстро, но не очень оптимально` - это как?

Comment: @aepot это так, что на относительно простой операции мы имеем цикл с ветвлением когда внутри (лишний if), а если на входе будет не int, а double (хоть и не по условию данной задачи) - тогда будет вообще караул. Логарифм считается, если не ошибаюсь за 100-200 тактов и не использует ax,bx,cx,dx регистры (ассемблеристы, поправьте если ошибаюсь), а значит не мешает в подавляющем большинстве случаев другому коду программы. Как итог, если что-то редко считать - то лучше цикл с делением, а если очень много длинных чисел - то цикл с условием - такой себе вариант...

Comment: Просто я это вижу как фоновая операция VS постоянный сброс конвеера с конкуренцией за основные регистры.

Comment: Десятичный логарифм по-моему считается медленней, чем 10 операций div+rem при переводе числа в десятичную систему счисления, но логарифм для количества знаков - вполне себе нормальное решение. Другое дело - имненно [перевод числа в строку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66499547/12888024). 1) есть сайт https://sharplab.io, там можно увидеть, какой IL и ассемблер генерируется для метода. 2) есть Benchmark.NET, позволяющий измерить сравнительную производительность методов. 3) по поводу регистров ax, bx... - это 16 бит (давно устарело); eax, ebx... - 32 бита (x86); rax, rbx... - x64.

Comment: @aepot про ax, bx, eax, ebx я просто как пример привёл, от программного кода же зависит что там и какие регистры будут использоваться, главное что они заниматься не будут, насчёт sharplab - единственное, что он может показать: call System.Math.Log10(Double), насчёт Benchmark.NET - вообще не показатель т.к. при большом числе ветвлений и сбросе конвеера производительность будет падать и бенч этого не покажет, нужно тестировать только в контексте, а где контекст брать - вопрос.

Comment: Используйте релизный режим, а не дебаг.

Comment: @aepot https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcDMACR2DC2A3utmbggsaebQJYB2w2AHtgLzZIAMvA3DVpkAJgHsArgCMANgFNsATw7YAsmGAALAHQAZUQHMeAChYBKAWiHk4SAJxGF5wdgC+6F0A== без разницы